# Problem with returning BigInteger value c#

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, biginteger

Hi im writing a simple client/server app using signalr and i am stuck with a problem i cannot resolve.

On the client i call the server method like this

```
BigInteger methodresponse = await _hubProxy.Invoke<BigInteger>("e50a3a806adcca88f1e7472da6e710b0f92202a93e4e47d6cde948dedb2e1206", PublicEncryption(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(licensekey)));
```

methodresponse being the return value from the server

and the server code is:

```
    public BigInteger e50a3a806adcca88f1e7472da6e710b0f92202a93e4e47d6cde948dedb2e1206(byte[] checkstring)
    {
        LoadPrivateFromXml();
        byte[] inputstring = PrivateDecryption(checkstring);
        //Convert Bytes to string
        string nobytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inputstring);

        PaillierCryptosys paillier = new PaillierCryptosys();

        int length = nobytes.Length;

        //Our 4 chosen values to play with
        BigInteger m1 = new BigInteger(length);
        BigInteger em1 = paillier.Encryption(m1);
        return em1;
    }
```

my issue is that on the server when debugging the value of em1 is what i want it to be, a very large BigInteger value however when i check the response from the server it is {"R":{"dataLength":32},"I":"1"} and the client recieves the value 0

i have searched the web for hours but i cannot seem to understand why this is happening

EDIT:
i will attach some photos of debugging

[Debugging server we can see the true value of em1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezp3W.png)

[Debugging client we can see what we recieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gucV7.png)

EDIT2:
Full client method code

```
            BigInteger methodresponse1= await _hubProxy.Invoke<BigInteger>("e50a3a806adcca88f1e7472da6e710b0f92202a93e4e47d6cde948dedb2e1206", PublicEncryption(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(licensekey)));

            BigInteger methodresponse2= await _hubProxy.Invoke<BigInteger>("e50a3a806adcca88f1e7472da6e710b0f92202a93e4e47d6cde948dedb2e1206", PublicEncryption(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timestamp.ToString())));

            PaillierCryptosys paillier = new PaillierCryptosys();
            BigInteger em1xem3 = (methodresponse1 * methodresponse2) % paillier.nsqr;
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(paillier.Decryption(em1xem3)));

            if (paillier.Decryption(em1xem3) == 47)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Success decrypted text [{paillier.Decryption(em1xem3)}] is equal to 47");
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(paillier.Decryption(em1xem3).ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("failed");
            }
```

EDIT3:

Trying as a string issue
[image: Trying as a string issue]

Comment: Seems like some serialization/deserialization logic is called for.

Comment: Its the probably the serialization/deserialization of the big int. Try .ToString() to see if it works in general

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing that the server side doesn't know how to serialize the return value from the function, so it probably doesn't return it at all, and then on the client side the deserializer assigns the default value. Try searching for something like "serialize BigInteger <your server-side framework>".

Comment: You see .ToString() does work however on the client im still working with a BigInteger class and BigInteger.Parse from system.numerics is incompatable with the BigInteger class im working with

Comment: @StarterCoder you seem to have proven it’s a serialization issue. Can you post the pertinent code in your setup?

Comment: @VictorWilson i added the relevant code of the client method under edit2

Comment: What if you return (and receive) the value as a string, and then use a string-based constructor or a string-based parse on the client?

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I editied to show what i tried earlier and the main issue when trying as a string and doing Biginteger.parse

Comment: The message states that the % operator is not supported on BigIntegers. The parsing might be working just fine...

Comment: In the image, you're doing System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse, but what I meant was to use your other BigInteger class; it either has it's own Parse method, or if it doesn't, it probably has a constructor taking in a string - try that. (Is it by any chance BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger? That one has a string-based constructor.)

Comment: The % operator can be used just fine on BigIntegers, however as soon as i involve SystemNumerics.BigIntegers it just breaks

Comment: the biginteger class im using is from https://github.com/rqg0717/Homomorphic-encryption/blob/master/Cryptosystem/Paillier/BigInteger.cs and i dont seem to see any mention of parse anywhere @FilipMilovanović

Comment: I'm guessing that paillier.nsqr is not System.Numerics.BigInteger, but the other one? That's probably why - the operands are of different types. The one you linked has this constructor `public BigInteger(string value, int radix)` - use it like this `BigInteger(methodresponse, 10)`

Comment: A general comment - you can't expect that custom `BigInteger` to be deserializable from a `System.Numerics.BigInteger`, so you'll probably find that if you can use the `System.Numerics` implementation as your return type, and also use that type when reading the API response in your client, the serialisation issues will be resolved.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović thank you very much by doing BigInteger test1 = new BigInteger(methodresponse, 10); it now worked correctly